# Boosting area chart makes it looking like a bar chart

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to enable boost mode on area chart but as a result it makes the chart looks like a bar chart.

What am I doing wrong ?

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
chart: {
    type: 'area'
},
boost:{
    useGPUTranslations:true
},
series: [{
        boostThreshold:1,
    name: 'USA',
    data: [
        6, 11, 32, 110, 235
    ]
}, {
    name: 'USSR/Russia',
    data: [
        5, 25, 50, 120, 150, 
    ]
}]
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/u8dLq4xc/1/

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a bug so I reported it on the Github issue channel where you can follow this thread: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/14207